# Microsoft Phone app not available in Australia from Apple site

Tags: phone-connector-mac

Where can I obtain a file for the Windows phone app for my Mac? Does anyone know of a link for a file? I run Snow Leopard and I want to connect my Lumia 540 to it. Anyone knows of an effective app to do this?

I have found a hack but I need the app. For some unfathomable reason, the Apple App for Lumia not available in Australia; does anyone has the file, or a link to one?

Comment: I didn't think the 8.x phones needed a specific app, as they should just connect as an MTP device?